# Atribuir valor a variável do tipo HiddenField está dando erro

Tags: c#

Tenho essa declaração:

```
HiddenField vhdfCdTipoUsuario = null;
```

Tenho essa atribuição:

```
vhdfCdTipoUsuario = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdfCdTipoUsuario");
```

Se faço isso, dá esse erro:

```
if ((vhdfCdTipoUsuario.Value != Session["DsTipoUsuario"]) && (Session["DsTipoUsuario"] != null))
                    vhdfCdTipoUsuario.Value = Session["DsTipoUsuario"].ToString();

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Como eu resolvo isso? O erro dá aqui:

```
vhdfCdTipoUsuario.Value = Session["DsTipoUsuario"].ToString();
```

A Session está ok(populada). Como eu trabalho com variáveis do tipo `HiddenField`?
Como atribuo valor a esse tipo de variável? Já removi o ToString() da Session e mesmo assim dá tilt.

Aqui está o código completo:

```
protected void rptGerenciaProcessos_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            //Declarações
            HiddenField vhdfCdTipoUsuario = null;
            LinkButton vlkbPriorizar = null;
            string teste = "";

            try
            {
                //Instâncias e Inicializalções
                vhdfCdTipoUsuario = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdfCdTipoUsuario");
                vlkbPriorizar = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lkbPriorizar");

                teste = Session["DsTipoUsuario"].ToString();

                if ((vhdfCdTipoUsuario != Session["DsTipoUsuario"]) && (Session["DsTipoUsuario"] != null))
                    vhdfCdTipoUsuario.Value = teste;

                //Desenvolvimento
                if (vhdfCdTipoUsuario != null)
                    if (int.Parse(vhdfCdTipoUsuario.Value) != 2 )
                        if (vlkbPriorizar != null)
                            vlkbPriorizar.Enabled = false;


            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Mensagem = (wucMensagens)Page.Master.FindControl("wucMasterMensagens");
                Mensagem.ExibirMensagem(wucMensagens.TipoAlerta.Erro, Ex.Source, Ex.Message, Ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Já tentou verificar se a linha de atribuição realmente atribui alguma coisa?

Comment: Sim, eu quero exatamente alterar essa linha, porque ela sempre trás um resultado não esperado. Como houve alteração no escopo, preciso é alterar essa linha: vhdfCdTipoUsuario = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdfCdTipoUsuario");

Comment: Mas você atribui antes do if?

Comment: Não,  o if está depois da atribuição.

Comment: Cara, teu código parece ok. Posta ele completo, pois pode ser problema de escopo. Além disso, através dum break point, veja qual dos objetos está disparando o erro, se o `vhdfCdTipoUsuario` ou `Session["DsTipoUsuario"]`.

Comment: Posta o stack da exception, assim fica mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: O erro está em vhdfCdTipoUsuario, já vi isso. Vou fazer uma edição e postar too o código.

Comment: Esse é o Stack Trace que eu peguei. at Scania.SOMC.Web.frmGESStatusPriorizar.rptGerenciaProcessos_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) in C:\Repositorio\ICSModuloCredito\Branches\ModuloCredito\ICS_MC\Scania.SOMC.Web\frmGESStatusPriorizar.aspx.cs:line 186

Comment: Do nada voltou a dar o erro. Isso tá osso.

Answer (score 0):

Comecei a executar e de repente não deu mais a exceção. Continua a mesma coisa, como no primeiro post:

```
if ((vhdfCdTipoUsuario != Session["DsTipoUsuario"]) && (Session["DsTipoUsuario"] != null))
                    vhdfCdTipoUsuario.Value = Session["DsTipoUsuario"].ToString();
```